# How to click on button inside table using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a page that has a table with different rows. I need to click on a button that is on a specific row as this:

```
<tr  valign="top" >
<td>Need to click this row button</td>
<td  width="100px" >
<select  name="aaaamm1" >
<option  value="specific_value_1.php" >1</option>
<option  value="specific_value_2.php" >2</option>
<option  value="specific_value_3" >3</option>
</select>
   </td>
<td  width="60px" >
    
<input  type="button" onclick="javascript:function);" value="Ver">
</td>
</tr>

<tr  valign="top" >
<td  >Another row</td>
...
```

I can't identify this specific row and click on that button, I'm using selenium on python.

Trying to click on the button inside an specific row of a table.

Comment: Assuming that you have found the row that you are looking at, why not just `.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')` and then `click()`. Or is your problem finding the specific row that contains that button?

Comment: @AndrewRyan my problem is finding the specific row that contains that button

Comment: What is different about each row? Couldn't you just look for each of the rows and just index into the row that you want (or does the row change)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML...

```
<tr  valign="top" >
    <td>Need to click this row button</td>
    <td  width="100px" >
        <select  name="aaaamm1" >
            <option  value="specific_value_1.php" >1</option>
            <option  value="specific_value_2.php" >2</option>
            <option  value="specific_value_3" >3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td  width="60px" >
        <input  type="button" onclick="javascript:function);" value="Ver">
    </td>
</tr>
```

To identify and click on the element:

```
<td>Need to click this row button</td>
```

You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath*, *preceding-sibling* and `<select>` tag:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[.//select[@name='aaaamm1']]//preceding-sibling::td[1]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *preceding-sibling* and `<input>` tag:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[.//input[@value='Ver']]//preceding-sibling::td[2]").click()
  ```